# how to send all files in a folder as email attachments in ruby

Tags: ruby, email-attachments

i am trying to send all files in a particular folder as email attachments using ruby .
How to read all files in a folder and send them as email attachment in ruby?
As of now  i am able to send one file as email attachment using the below code.

```
    require 'net/smtp'
    filename = "/tmp/test.txt"
    # Read a file and encode it into base64 format
    filecontent = File.read(filename)
    encodedcontent = [filecontent].pack("m")   # base64
    marker = "AUNIQUEMARKER"
    body =<<EOF
    This is a test email to send an attachement.
    EOF
    # Define the main headers.
    part1 =<<EOF 
    From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.net>
    To: A Test User <test@todmain.com>
    Subject: Sending Attachement
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=#{marker}
    --#{marker}
    EOF
    # Define the message action
    part2 =<<EOF
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit
    #{body}
    --#{marker}
    EOF

   # Define the attachment section
   part3 =<<EOF
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; name=\"#{filename}\"
   Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="#{filename}"
   #{encodedcontent}
   --#{marker}--
   EOF
   mailtext = part1 + part2 + part3
   # Let's put our code in safe area 
   begin 
       Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
       smtp.sendmail(mailtext, 'me@fromdomain.net',
                      ['test@todmain.com'])
   end
   rescue Exception => e  
     print "Exception occured: " + e  
   end
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're implementing a mail service from scratch? Would it not be much easier to just use an existing gem, e.g. https://github.com/mikel/mail ?

Comment: i am completely new to ruby . In that case as well , how to send all files in a folder as attachments .

Answer (score 0):

The important part here is to loop over all files in a directory, and add each of them as an attachment.

I could modify your original code to do this, but there are much easier solutions.

For example, using a ruby gem such as `mail` (https://github.com/mikel/mail), you can simplify the code a great deal:

```
Mail.deliver do
  from     'me@fromdomain.net'
  to       'mytest@todmain.com'
  subject  'Sending Attachement'
  body     'This is a test email to send an attachement.'
  Dir.glob('/tmp/files_to_attach/*.txt') do |file|
    add_file file
  end
end
```